# How do I play random songs from variables and lists with python and pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm brand new here and I'm trying to make a simple program to play shuffle music in python.

I've tried using pygame.mixer.music and list variables to pick a random song and play it. keep in mind I'm brand new and have no idea what I'm doing.

```
import pygame 
from pygame.locals import *
import random
import pygame.mixer

L = ['Relax.mp3', 'Wanchu_Back.mp3', 'Some_Chords.mp3', 'Green_Gusher.mp3',]
S = random.randint(0, len(L))

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.50)
pygame.mixer.music.load(L)
pygame.mixer.music.play(S)
```

I tried multiple things but I keep getting this message

```
pygame.error: Couldn't read from RWops
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pygame.mixer.music.load()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.load) expects single filename or single file-object, not list.

```
pygame.mixer.music.load( filename )
```

ie.

```
pygame.mixer.music.load( L[0] )
```

---

If you need random filename then you can use

```
filename = random.choice(L)
pygame.mixer.music.load( filename )
```

---

To make sure it is good to use full path to file.